\newkeytheoremstyle: failure to obtain a shadow
It seems that the line shadow = {.75mm}{-.75mm}{0mm}{#1!15!white} is broken in my code. What am I missing?
% Initial source: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/727022/6880

\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{skins}

\usepackage{keytheorems}

\tcbset{
  thmstyle/.style={
    colback  = #1!5,
    colframe = #1!25!white,
    shadow   = {.75mm}{-.75mm}{0mm}{#1!15!white} % This line has no effect...
 }
}

\newkeytheoremstyle{tcb-standard}{
  headpunct     = {},
  notebraces    = {}{}, 
  noteseparator = {: }, 
  notefont      = \bfseries, 
  bodyfont      = \normalfont,
}

\newcommand{\projetnewstyle}[1]{%
  \newkeytheoremstyle{tcb-standard-#1}{
    inherit-style         = tcb-standard,
    tcolorbox-no-titlebar = {thmstyle=#1}
  }
}

\projetnewstyle{red}
\projetnewstyle{green}

\newkeytheorem{test}[
  name=Test,
  style=tcb-standard-red]

\newkeytheorem{blub}[style=tcb-standard-green]

\begin{document}

\begin{test}
  Bla, blo, bli, bla, blo, bli, bla, blo, bli, bla, blo, bli, bla, blo, bli, bla...
\end{test}
\begin{blub}
  Bla, blo, bli, bla, blo, bli, bla, blo, bli, bla, blo, bli, bla, blo, bli, bla...
\end{blub}

\end{document}


The tcolorbox manual says

The skin standard does not support these shadows, but most other skins, e. g. enhanced.

So just add enhanced.
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{skins}

\usepackage{keytheorems}

\tcbset{
  thmstyle/.style={
    enhanced,
    colback  = #1!5,
    colframe = #1!25!white,
    shadow   = {.75mm}{-.75mm}{0mm}{#1!15!white} % This line has no effect...
 }
}

\newkeytheoremstyle{tcb-standard}{
  headpunct     = {},
  notebraces    = {}{}, 
  noteseparator = {: }, 
  notefont      = \bfseries, 
  bodyfont      = \normalfont,
}

\newcommand{\projetnewstyle}[1]{%
  \newkeytheoremstyle{tcb-standard-#1}{
    inherit-style         = tcb-standard,
    tcolorbox-no-titlebar = {thmstyle=#1}
  }
}

\projetnewstyle{red}
\projetnewstyle{green}

\newkeytheorem{test}[
  name=Test,
  style=tcb-standard-red]

\newkeytheorem{blub}[style=tcb-standard-green]

\begin{document}

\begin{test}
  Bla, blo, bli, bla, blo, bli, bla, blo, bli, bla, blo, bli, bla, blo, bli, bla...
\end{test}
\begin{blub}
  Bla, blo, bli, bla, blo, bli, bla, blo, bli, bla, blo, bli, bla, blo, bli, bla...
\end{blub}

\end{document}


This was misplaced in my old example. I fix that now. "Thanks twice"!
